# Jetty no longer includes request URL path as part of thread id?

Tags: jetty, logback

We are using Logback with Jetty and our appender config looks like:

```xml
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

With Jetty 7.5.4 the %thread property would be expanded to include the URL path of the request along with the thread id -- something like [qtp2105333421-78 - /requested/url]

Since upgrading to 7.6.8 it appears that the request path is no longer included -- logs now contain only [qtp2105333421-78].

I've only been able to find discussion of someone trying to exclude the request path from the log. I'm trying to include it now that it's missing and I couldn't find anything that sounded relevant in the Jetty changelog. Is this something that has been removed, or is it possible to change the logging pattern to get access to the request path again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request path in the Thread name is a DEBUG only features in 7.5.4

See [`org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest()` from Jetty 7.5.4 line #407](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-7.5.4.v20111024/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpConnection.java#L407)

It is still present as a DEBUG feature, but the move to Jetty 7.6.x had some refactoring that might be biting you.

See [`org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest()` from Jettty 7.6.10 line #431](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-7.6.10.v20130312/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractHttpConnection.java#L431).

Note the class change `HttpConnection` to `AbstractHttpConnection`

Comment: Thank you. Enabling debug logging for Jetty did indeed reveal the path URL.